# Is it possible to use MacBook as a display for Mac Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mac-pro

I want to use a Mac Pro on the display of a MacBook. That's because I mainly use MacBook and now would like to use Mac Pro only when I need more power.

But since I'm a traveler for all year round, there is no choice to use iMac or MacBook Pro.

So is it possible to use the display, keyboard, and trackpad of a MacBook to use Mac Pro?

Comment: Cloud/LAN gaming software like Parsec is good for this, you can use any cheap computer as a simple video player + still use it’s keyboard and mouse to interact with the host machine. Pretty much, the only latency comes from transcoding h264/h265 which is around 7ms for 1080p in some guy’s test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some computers that have a Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt port as an external display.

You can view the contents of your Mac on the display of another Mac using Target Display Mode, a feature in OS X. Target Display Mode lets you use a Mac as the external display for another “primary” Mac. In some cases, you can also use Target Display Mode to play the sound from your primary Mac on the speakers of the external Mac. For example, a MacBook Pro could use a 27-inch iMac as the display and play its audio on the iMac as well.

After connecting the computers and turning on Target Display Mode, the external display Mac acts like any other external display. Apps that were open on the external display Mac remain open even though you can’t see their windows.

**Display the contents of your Mac on an iMac with Thunderbolt**

If you have an iMac with Thunderbolt, any other Mac with Thunderbolt can use it as a display. The iMac will play both the video and audio from the other Mac.

1. Connect the Thunderbolt cable to the Thunderbolt ports  on each computer.
2. Make sure both Mac computers are turned on and awake.
3. Press Command (⌘)-F2 on the keyboard of the external display Mac.
4. If you want the external display Mac to play audio as well as video from the primary Mac, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Sound, then click Output.

Then select the external display Mac in the list of devices.

**Display the contents of your Mac on a 27-inch iMac with a Mini DisplayPort**

If you have a 27-inch iMac with a Mini DisplayPort , any other Mac with a Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt port  can use it as a display. Make sure you have a Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable.

If the primary Mac has a Thunderbolt port, it can play its audio and video on the iMac. If the primary Mac has a Mini DisplayPort, the iMac may be able to play its audio. To see if it can, go to the primary Mac, choose Apple menu > About This Mac, click System Report, then select Audio in the Hardware category. A list of your computer’s audio devices appears. If HDMI Output or HDMI/DisplayPort output is listed, your computer’s Mini DisplayPort can send audio. Make sure you use a Mini DisplayPort cable that carries both audio and video.

1. Connect the Mini DisplayPort cable to the ports on each computer.
2. Make sure both computers are turned on and awake.
3. Press Command (⌘)-F2 on the iMac.
4. If you want the external display Mac to play audio as well as video from the primary Mac, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Sound, then click Output.

Then select the iMac in the list of devices.

**Also you could enable Screen Sharing on the MacPro and connect to it from the MacBook**

or

**Check out https://symless.com/synergy**

Comment: Also check out https://symless.com/synergy

Comment: Do you know the trackpad and keyboard can also be used along with the display?

Comment: @Blaszard Cloud/LAN gaming software does that over ethernet and h264/h265 with like 7ms delay, I would recommend Parsec but I’m sure the others are fine